I can't draw a circle with inside lines
I'm trying to draw an example of an open neighborhood in R^2 and I can't find why, after the compiler, lines appear outside the circle.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=1.0}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(3,3)
\pscircle[fillstyle=vlines](1.5,1.5){1}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}



Welcome. Are you possibly compiling with TeXworks? With another editor your code compile correctly. Actually there is no solution: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1520

Compilation under TeXLive (LaTeX > PS > PDF, LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX) all compile fine.

show your complete log file!

I think that this is an answer. If I compile with the XeLaTeX of TeXworks 0.6.9 I have the same output of your code:

Looking the pdf you can see that the output is fine:

Related:

Rendering issue in TeXworks
https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1435
Ugly Rendering of the output visualization of TeXworks

The problem, yet, is visible.

I cannot see the problem with 0.6.8 ("github") [r.6b1c6ab, ]
